# python append two values to two columns same row if new values

Tags: python, numpy, append

I have to write a file with two columns of values. The values are incremented/calculated in a loop.

The values must be written on the same row, making then two columns. The raw index equals the first value, 'j'.

this is what I have tried:

```
import math
n = 3
output_file ='test.txt'
for j in range(0,n+1):
    Y0 = 12*math.sqrt(j)
    RES = (j, Y0)
    with open(output_file, "a+") as f:
        # Move read cursor to line j
        f.seek(j)
        f.write(str(' '.join(map(str, RES)))+'\n')
```

the remaining issue is that if I run the script again then the new lines get appended to the file while I would like them to overwrite the previous results.

as example if the result for j=2 is calculated again then I would like to overwrite the values of the second column in the raw where j=2 only, and leave unchanged the others.

output should be like:

```
0 0.0
1 12.0
2 16.970562748477143
3 20.784609690826528
```

how should I modify my code to do so ?
preferably with numpy rather than panda

Comment: change the last line to `f.write('\n'+ ' '.join(map(str, RES)))`

Comment: thanks Sembei, I have modified my post accordingly. found with your solution and moving the /n to the end !

Answer (score 0):

I would simply rewrite the whole file using the option "w"

```
import math

n = 3
content = ''

for j in range(0,n+1):
    Y0 = 12*math.sqrt(j)
    RES = (j, Y0)
    content += str(' '.join(map(str, RES)))+'\n'
        
output_file = 'test.txt'
with open(output_file, "w") as f:
    f.write(content)
```